# passing in json variable into sendgrid's dynamic_template_data

Tags: javascript, json, sendgrid

I'm having some trouble passing into a variable that holds a json object into sendgrid's dynamic_template_data. My setup looks like this:

```
  const send = async (address, mentions) => {
    console.log('mentions json obj', mentions)
    let name = "john"

    try {
      let config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.sendgridKey}`,
        }
      }
      let data = {
        personalizations: [
          {
            to: [
              {
                email: `${address}`,
              },
            ],
            dynamic_template_data: {
              name: name,
              allMentions: mentions
            }
          }
        ],
        from: {
          email: "email@email.com",
          name: "Mentionscrawler Team"
        },
        template_id: process.env.template_id,
      }
      await axios.post("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", data, config)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, 'failing here>>>>>>>')
    }
  }
```

when I console.log mentions, which is json, and paste the code I get from the terminal directly into the allMentions key, it works. but when I just pass in mentions itself, nothing shows up on the sent email. I've been very confused the last few hours why this is happening. Any advice appreciated.

edit: i should also note that allmentions is an object with keys that hold arrays. So I'm looking to iterate over those arrays. Again, this totally all works if I just paste in directly what mentions is, but passing in mentions is giving me an issue.

Thank you very much,

Comment: How do you obtain `mentions`? Through an API call?

Comment: initially its info grabbed from our db,  and then passed in to this function from another one @CodeWalker

Comment: Sounds like a problem with asynchrony.

Comment: Thank you @codewalker. I can view mentions using console log just fine though. Does that not matter when it comes to a sync code?

Answer (score 1):

just realized what was wrong. sendgrid's template requires a json object, so I assumed that I needed to use json.stringify on my mentions obj. Turns out I didn't need to do that, as long as all values are in string format.

Comment: After a lot of tinkering and fighting with this, I followed your answer and removed the `JSON.stringify` code and "boom!" it works!  Not sure why that is the case, but glad I figured it out!

Comment: Wow! Glad it was helpful!